# Using OpenSearch Python bulk api to insert data to multiple indices

Tags: api, rest, elasticsearch, opensearch

This document shows how bulk data with multiple index can be inserted using POST request in curl: https://opensearch.org/docs/latest/opensearch/index-data/

If I have data in this format,

```
[
{ "index": { "_index": "index-2022-06-08", "_id": "<id>" } }
{ "A JSON": "document" }
{ "index": { "_index": "index-2022-06-09", "_id": "<id>" } }
{ "A JSON": "document" }
{ "index": { "_index": "index-2022-06-10", "_id": "<id>" } }
{ "A JSON": "document" }
]
```

Bulk request should take the index name from `"_index": "index-2022-06-08"`

I was trying to use OpenSearch-py library to do the same but I can't find any example snippet does that. I am using this format to send request from AWS Lambda.

```
client = OpenSearch(
            hosts = [{'host': host, 'port': 443}],
            http_auth = awsauth,
            use_ssl = True,
            verify_certs = True,
            connection_class = RequestsHttpConnection
            )
        
        resp = helpers.bulk(client, logs, index= index_name, max_retries = 3)
```

Here, I've to mention index_name as a parameter in bulk request so it's not taking index_name from data itself. If I don't mention index_name in parameter, I get error 4xx index_name missing.

I was also looking into bulk api source code: https://github.com/opensearch-project/opensearch-py/blob/main/opensearchpy/helpers/actions.py#L373

It doesn't look like index_name is a mandatory parameter.

Can anyone help me with what am I missing?

Comment: @Divyank Link is dead

Answer (score 6):

I came across the same issue and found the solution in the [elasticsearch.py bulk-helpers documentation](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/helpers.html#bulk-helpers). When the documents are provided in the `_source-structure` that the search-endpoint returns it works.

Call of the bulk-method:

```
resp = helpers.bulk(
    self.opensearch,
    actions,
    max_retries=3,
)
```

Where `actions` is a list of dictionaries like this:

```
[{
    '_op_type': 'update',
    '_index': 'index-name',
    '_id': 42,
    '_source': {
        "title": "Hello World!",
        "body": "..."
    }
}]
```

`_op_type` can be used as an additional field to define the action(`index`, `update`, `delete`,...) that should be invoked for the document.

Hope this helps anyone coming across the same issue!

Answer (score 1):

Using the below code hope you can index using bulk method, there are two methods for indexing the documents in the opensearch one of the method is bulk method

```py
from opensearchpy import OpenSearch, helpers
from opensearchpy.helpers import bulk

client = OpenSearch(
    hosts=[{"host": "localhost", "port": 9200}],
    http_auth=("admin", "admin"),
    use_ssl=True,
    verify_certs=False,
    ssl_assert_hostname=False,
    ssl_show_warn=False,
)

inputtobeindexed = [
    {"index": {"_index": "index-2022-06-08", "_id": "<id>"}},
    {"A JSON": "document"},
    {"index": {"_index": "index-2022-06-09", "_id": "<id>"}},
    {"A JSON": "document"},
    {"index": {"_index": "index-2022-06-10", "_id": "<id>"}},
    {"A JSON": "document"},
]

search_index_name = "yourindexname"
bulk_data = [
    {"_index": search_index_name, "_id": i, "_source": doc} for i, doc in enumerate()
]

bulk(client, bulk_data)
```